# HTML href on Gmaps issue : My Location doesn't work on Microsoft edge

Tags: html, google-maps, reactjs, href, microsoft-edge

I'm making a website and I have a button which open a google map from the user location to somewhere else.

```html
<a href={'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=Nexapp'} target="_blank">
    //Button here             
</a>
```

The problem is that My Location give me a random gym in the USA when I'm click on the link with Microsoft Edge. [Here's a screenshot of the result](https://gyazo.com/670b5198d5e53b4aa9852e767b611da4) The other browser are giving me my location though...

Anyone have an idea why and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Here's the code of my component (I'm using Reactjs)

```
<div id="content" className={styles.mapSection}>
            <GoogleMap
                latitude={46.829131}
                longitude={-71.279030}
                zoom={14}
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                marker={false}
                mapOptions={mapOptions} />

            <div className={styles.mapOverlay}>
                <h1 className={`text ${styles.mapText}`}>
                    <FormattedMessage id="googleText" {...messages.googleText} />
                    <span className={styles.city}>
                        <FormattedMessage id="quebec" {...messages.quebec} />
                    </span>
                </h1>
                <a className={`link ${styles.mapButton}`} href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr=Nexapp" target="_blank">
                    <ChevronRightButton mobile={mobile} text={<FormattedMessage id="locationButton" {...messages.locationButton} />} />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The `<a>` doesn't change but @Sampson wanted for code :P

Comment: This HTML syntax is invalid; can you provide additional context? Are you using a framework or something? Also, which version of Microsoft Edge are you presently testing with? Your link appears to work for me: http://i.imgur.com/C8bBRD4.gif

Comment: I'm using Reactjs so the syntax is valid

Comment: Can you boil this example down to as few lines of code as possible? I'd love to look a little deeper into this for you.

Comment: I added more line of code to my question ;)

Comment: I'm looking for a functional reduction; as few lines of code that *reproduce* the issue. With this, we can troubleshoot.

Comment: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkhekmt8/) is doing the issue on EDGE ONLY , which is the problem.

Comment: Appears to work for me in Microsoft Edge 13: http://imgur.com/a/9HyEH

Comment: That's not the good destination XD But it's not the problem

Comment: I don't understand, Benoit. I see the same thing in Edge 13 and Chrome 51.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get "My Location" in any browser. Not sure if you previously allowed the browsers to view your location or what, but for me it did not work in IE or Chrome.

The only way I know to get a users location is to use the Google Maps API to find it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#DetectingUserLocation